# JSLint: Using a function before it's defined error

Tags: javascript, jslint

I'm using JSLint to verify most of my external Javascript files, but the largest amount of errors I'm getting is from functions being used before they're defined.

**Is this really an issue I should worry about**?

It seems Firefox, IE7 and Chrome don't care. Functions like the popular `init()` (which I use often) normally stick at the top as that makes sense to me (I like to pretend it's analogous to `main()`) will, according to JSLint, need to be pushed to the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you declare functions using the `function` keyword, you can use them before they're declared. However, if you declare a function via another method (such as using a function expression or the `Function` constructor), you have to declare the function before you use it. See [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) on the Mozilla Developer Network for more information.

Assuming you declare all your functions with the `function` keyword, I think it becomes a programming-style question. Personally, I prefer to structure my functions in a way that seems logical and makes the code as readable as possible. For example, like you, I'd put an `init` function at the top, because it's where everything starts from.

Comment: I prefer init-method atop as well. So functions it uses go below. How to ignore or hack this error as it blocks me from seeing next JsLint errors in code? I want a general approach to keep my style, but see this error not.

Answer (score 87):

As this is the top rated google hit and other people might not be seeing it at first in the jslint tool, there is a option called "Tolerate misordered definitions" that allows you to hide this type of error.

```
/*jslint latedef:false*/
```

Comment: Setting that option to `true` does not seem to "solve" this problem for me.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue as Markus.

Comment: Could you share your javascript? @M.Herold

Comment: @PeterMajeed No, it's not. Chris is not asking about how to tolerate misordered definitions.

Answer (score 33):

If you're using jshint you can set `latedef` to `nofunc`, which will ignore late function definitions only.

Documentation - http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#latedef

Example usage:

```
/* jshint latedef:nofunc */

noop();

function noop() {}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the 2014 solution.

Comment: Is this solution for jshint only? I use "Brackets" and I get a lot of lint warnings. Should lint be compatible with this hint solution. I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 11):

From jslint's website (http://www.jslint.com/lint.html), you can read about a /*global*/ directive that allows you to set variables that are assumed to be declared elsewhere.

Here is an example (put this at the top of the file):

```
/*global var1,var2,var3,var4,var5*/
```

The :true :false is not actually needed from my experience, but it looks like it's recommended from what I read on the site.

Make sure the initial global statement is on the same line as `/*`, or else it breaks.

Comment: Also for me the word global has to be directly after the asterisk, with no spaces or else it will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

To disable this warning in `jshint` for all files, place this in your `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
   "latedef": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it is very unfortunate the latedef option was removed. This is essential when trying to create a 'class' with an interface at the top, ie,

```
function SomeClass() {
   var self = this;
   self.func = func;

   function func {
      ...
   }
}
```

This style is very common but does not pass jsLint because func is 'used' before being defined. Having to use global for each 'member' function is a total pain.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.jshintrc` file, set:

```
  "latedef": "nofunc",
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare the offending function at the top

eg:
var init;

.... but then you'll have to remove the "var" when you get to the true definition further down:

init = function() {
};

Comment: Warning: `init = function(){}`  is not the same as `function init() {}`
ECMAScript has different rules for anonymous functions, that is what the first is.