# WHY JSLint complains: "someFunction() was used before it was defined"?

Tags: javascript, jslint, hoisting

Searching for the JSLint error "was used before it was defined" i've found these:

- [JSLint: Using a function before it's defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806163/jslint-using-a-function-before-its-defined-error)
- [Function was used before it was defined - JSLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963161/function-was-used-before-it-was-defined-jslint)
- [JSLint: was used before it was defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621162/jslint-was-used-before-it-was-defined)
- [jsLint error: “somefunction() was used before it was defined”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425147/jslint-error-somefunction-was-used-before-it-was-defined)
- [jslint - Should we tolerate misordered definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744692/jslint-should-we-tolerate-misordered-definitions)

## Problem

None of those answers **WHY** the error is shown.

## Elaboration

According to the [ECMA-262 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) functions are evaluated before execution starts, hence all functions declared using the `function` keyword are available to all the code idenpendent of the place they were declared (assuming they are acessible on that scope).

This is otherwise known as **hoisting**.

Douglas Crockford seems to think it is better to declare every function before the code that uses it regardless of the **hoisting** effect.

According to [StackOverflowNewbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253976/stackoverflownewbie) in his [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425147/jslint-error-somefunction-was-used-before-it-was-defined), this raises some code organization problems. Not to mention some people, like me, prefer to declare their functions underneath the main/init code.

On those questions there are some ways to avoid or fix the error, such as using function expressions vs function declarations. But none of them showed me the reason of the error. Not even [Crockford's site](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html).

## Question(s)

**Why** is it an error to call a function before the declaration, even if it was declared using the `function` keyword?

Is it better to use function expressions instead of function declaration in the JSLint context? If one is preferred, why?

### Note

**Not** looking for answers like:

- Crockford is a tyrant
- Is just Crockford's opinion

Thank you :*

Comment: But is **is** Crockford's opinion!

Comment: Does jshint complain about this?

Comment: JSLint is a tool to check if your code adheres to the coding style Crockford likes. It's not meant for validating against the specification or for ensuring compatibility with JS engines.  "It's just Crockford's opinion" is a valid (and only) answer to most JSLint questions.

Comment: Simply stating that "it is his opinion" is not constructive and doesn't help anyone. He has some experience and it is worth knowing why he thought it would be better this way, instead of simply complain about JSLint and change to JSHint. Duscuting the WHY often brings me great knowledge. If you want to dump a good opportunity to learn by simply stating it's his opinion, that's your choice.

Comment: Not sure what in my question deserves a downvote!?! A comment on that would be great.

Comment: @DaggNabbit don't know, didn't try. This is for a personal project and I'm using JSLint to have a little experience with it. If my code passes a less permissive linter than I know it's good code, right? :D

Comment: You know it's carefully-formatted code, at least ;)

Comment: JSHint allows the warning to be disabled with /*jslint latedef:false*/: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9512299/259

Comment: Thank you for pointing out something many people seem to forget..  i.e: Why is this an error?  Nothing but silence or "this guy says so" This question should be upvoted a lot..

Answer (score 3):

It is NOT an error (your code does work after all). The concern with this is that declaring function after it has been used decreases readibility of the code. Someone reading your code may think this function is declared somewhere in outer scope. This can be especially confusing, if you overwrite popular functions/constructors like `Date`

Comment: I used error as a manner of speech. Thanks for your answer. I was imagining something like that :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you're going to do what jshint/jslint say, and define functions before their use, then there's no overwhelming reason (other than aesthetic) to prefer function declarations over function expressions.

Here's my opinion: Declaring functions after they're used is bad, *unless* it's very clear that you're referring to a function that's declared in the same scope.  This can either be a result of good naming or proximity.

For example, you're returning a reference to the declared function immediately before it's declared.  Here, you've clarified the intent of your outer function, which is equally as important, and the reader knows they don't have to scan downward to see if there is additional code specific to the outer scope.

That said, I also think sprinkling function declarations amongst your outer scope's code of intent is also horrible for readability, but maybe I'm a terrible person.