# Jslint function hoisting error

Tags: angularjs, json

Why does the following piece of code:

```
angular.module('avafriqueWebApp')
  .service('MainService', function ($http) {

    var mainService = {
      getMenNewArrivals: getMenNewArrivals,
      getWomenNewArrivals: getWomenNewArrivals
    };
    return mainService;

    function getMenNewArrivals()
    {
      return $http.get('data/men-new-arrivals.json');
    }

    function getWomenNewArrivals()
    {
      return $http.get('data/women-new-arrivals.json');
    }

  });
```

all of a sudden return this error message:

[image]

I thought function hoisting in this fashion and crafting some type of interface was a good thing?

Comment: Which part is not clear?

Comment: @PM77-1 this is a pattern I normally follow in my code. I am not sure why it is returning this error message all of a sudden

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WHY JSLint complains: "someFunction() was used before it was defined"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786621/why-jslint-complains-somefunction-was-used-before-it-was-defined)