# Performance userscript injecting code

Tags: greasemonkey, code-injection, userscripts

I have a question about userscripts. Is it faster to have this in before or after of the main function initiateFlasher?

```
if (typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' && unsafeWindow.jQuery) {
    initiateFlasher(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
} else {
    function addScript(callback) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.text = '(' + callback.toString() + ')();';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
    addScript(initiateFlasher);
}


function initiateFlasher(arg) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The speed difference will be negligible.
But it's better form to define `initiateFlasher()` first. (When in doubt, use [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/).)

This is a good habit to get into because, even though a function declaration will work on most browsers before or after, [function expressions or function constructors will not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806163/jslint-using-a-function-before-its-defined-error/806355#806355).

Comment: Thanks! I saw that in Safari console it complained about initateFlasher() wasn't defined first.